# Make delete key on custom in-app keyboard delete text from other edit text

Tags: android, kotlin

I've made a custom in-app keyboard (by following [this tutorial](https://ssaurel.medium.com/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps-a0a6c6e1e289)). But I'd like it to delete text from a different edit text when the delete key is pressed. Is this possible to achieve?

This is my onClick code in my keyboard activity file:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    if (v.id == R.id.button_delete) {
        // Delete key is pressed.
    } else {
        // Regular key is pressed.
        val value = keyValues[v.id]
        inputConnection?.commitText(value, 1)
    }

}
```

Let me know if there's anything else you'd like to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by putting a character e.g: 'd' into the edittext like so:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    if (v.id == R.id.button_delete) {
        inputConnection?.commitText("d", 1)
    } else {
        val value = keyValues[v.id]
        inputConnection?.commitText(value, 1)
    }
}
```

Then in the activity that controlls the edittext's layout, e.g: for me it was `PasscodeActivity`, put a `TextWatcher` that detects when the text inside of the edittext has changed.

```
private fun setEditTextListener() {
        val inputEl = findViewById<EditText>(resources.getIdentifier("inputEl", "id", packageName))
        inputEl.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(textBeforeChangedStr: CharSequence?, startNum: Int, countNum: Int, afterNum: Int) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(textAfterChangedStr: CharSequence?, startNum: Int, beforeNum: Int, countNum: Int) {
                ...
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(editableEl: Editable?) {
                if (inputEl.text.toString() == "d") { // The 'd' character is put into the edittext when the delete key is pressed.
                    clearOtherEditText()
                }
                ...
            }
        })
}
```

Then in the function `clearOtherEditText()` I put in some code to get rid of the text in a different edittext like so:

```
val otherInputEl = findViewById<EditText>(resources.getIdentifier("otherInput", "id", packageName))
otherInputEl.text.clear()
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

try below solution

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
if (v.id == R.id.button_delete) {
    // Delete key is pressed.
      **inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0)**
     } else {
    // Regular key is pressed.
    val value = keyValues[v.id]
    inputConnection?.commitText(value, 1)
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pinki, but I've already got a solution to this.